# Can’t get indexPath of TableViewCell in nestled CollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I’ve got a tableView with collectionViews nestled in each tableViewCell. 
Each tableViewCell is a movie genre and the collectionViewCells would be the movies.
I’m trying to tell the collectionView which TableView indexPath it is so it can display the correct data.

The problem I’m having is as you scroll through the collectionView (and TableView) the numbers change (I’ve got a label in the collectionView cell displaying the TableView indexPath.row). Also if I scroll to the end of a collectionView in the first tableView cell, the collectionViewCell in the 4th or so tableViewCell will also be scrolled to the end, as if they are ‘linked’.

To get the nestled layout I’m following this tut https://youtu.be/4XnXHov2lQU
I’d initially setup the collectionView from the TableViewCell Class but as explained in the video this doesn’t conform to MVC.

To get the `tableViewIndexPath` I just set a variable in the TableView `cellForRowAt` then set the label in the collectionView to this.

What would be the correct way to do this as I’ve seen other questions and answered posted on this but pretty much all give the same problem.

**EDIT -**
**TableViewController.swift**

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var tableViewIndexPath = Int()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()          
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 230
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! tableViewCellClass

        tableViewIndexPath = indexPath.row

        cell.collectionView.dataSource = self
        cell.collectionView.reloadData()

        return cell
    }
}

extension TableViewController : UICollectionViewDataSource {

    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "collectionViewCell", for: indexPath)

        let title = cell.viewWithTag(4) as! UILabel
        title.text = String(tableViewIndexPath)

        return cell
    }

}
```

**TableViewCellClass.swift**

```
class tableViewCellClass: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    var indexPathForCell: IndexPath?

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        self.collectionView.contentOffset = .zero
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question clearly has a lack of code, but from your description, I suppose that you have a problem with cells reusing.

Let's say, that you scrolled `UICollectionView` at the first cell to the right. If after that, you start to scroll you `UITableView` down, your `UITableViewCells` will be recused. So your `4th` `UICollectionView` will be in fact, the first cell that had been reused. `Reused` means that it is the very same cell. And since you scroll the first cell to the right, its `CollectionView` has the same `contentOffset` value and it looks like it was scrolled.

Every reusable cell has a method `prepateForReuse()` that can be overridden. In that method, you can reset all your cell parameters to default values. For example, I'll assume that, at your table view cell class, you have a `collectionView` object. In that case, you need to do next

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    self.collectionView.contentOffset = .zero
}
```

After that, every reused cell will be automatically returned to its initial position. Also, when you'll scroll you table view back to the top,  the first `UICollectionView` will be at the initial position as well.

Comment: Yes that basically the problem I’m having. I tried to reload the collectionView in prepareForReuse() but it doesn’t keep the users scrolled to position in the collection view (for obvious reasons). (Excuse the no code, not at my computer at the moment, will edit some in)

Comment: The App Store uses the same layout but still keeps the position and there not glitching etc. Would you know how they have set it up?

Comment: If you want to keep the user scroll positions for each cell, you need to store them somehow in a separate array, for example.

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: It's a completely different question. Your question was about why are your new cells are scrolled *as if they are ‘linked’*. I've tried to explain you why and how to make them not to be scrolled initially.

Comment: @Junaid But if you need an advice, you need to have an array of `CPoint` there you will store offsets of each cell. You will save values of reused cells and take values from this array for cells that will appear. Not the best solution, but the best I can give without any details.

Comment: Thanks for the guideline. Could you add more detail regarding this to your answer above as it is kind of related. If you use the method above you would want to preserve the users position. If not I’ll post another question for this specifically.

Comment: I’ve been doing some more testing and the solution doesn’t work properly. When you first load the view all the first collectionView has the tableView indexPath of the last tableViewCell. It’s onlt when you scroll through and back that everything shows the correct numbers.

Comment: @Junaid What do you mean by "the first collectionView has the tableView indexPath of the last tableViewCell"? Probably you're doing something wrong

Comment: Here’s a video of what happens - https://drive.google.com/open?id=1vez3BslhP48q0pddgdvRCkXAM4HfIQ-f

Comment: Oh, I see. But this has nothing in common with your question and my answer (or solution). You simply have some problems with cells setup. It's not about reusing them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180620/discussion-between-junaid-and-yury-imashev).

Answer (score 0):

In your tableview cell class add extension of collectionview delegate and data source, define your layout and configure collectionview cells.

In your view controller class go to cellForRowAIndex and call the method of tableview cells class like configureCollectionView(at section: indexPath.row) // to capture the row index

In your tableview class make sure you define configure method that sets the collectionview delegate, datasource and reloads data

Doing this will allow you to keep the scroll positions of each row to be scrolled in a way that doesn't seemed linked.